# How can I query a tileset from ARCGIS map service to extract a raster image?

Tags: r, arcgis, r-raster, bounding-box, arcgis-js-api

I am attempting to build a url query to access a ARCGIS tileset ([map here](https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/gGHDlz6USftL5Pau/arcgis/rest/services/UrbanCanopy_2018_L5_17_v4/MapServer?view=wmtsview&cacheKey=927c39a5a5923c8f) and [services directory info here](https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/gGHDlz6USftL5Pau/arcgis/rest/services/UrbanCanopy_2018_L5_17_v4/MapServer?f=html&cacheKey=927c39a5a5923c8f)) and convert it to a raster image in R. I see that the "Export Tiles Allowed" condition is set to false on the services directory, so I am trying to query through the ["Tile Map"](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/tile-map.htm) option instead. On the documentation, I see that the correct format is `https://<mapservice-url>/tilemap/<level>/<row>/<column>/<width>/<height>`, but I am unsure how to build this url in order to extract a raster later.

Overall, I would like to query the tileset that is cropped to a Census Block Group bounding box and extract a raster image. The following is an example of a Census Block Group polygon and obtaining bounding box points:

```
library(sf)
library(tigris)
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)
library(raster)
library(exactextractr)

ex_cbg <-
  block_groups("06","081", cb = T) %>%
  st_transform(2227) %>% 
  .[1,]

box_list <-
    st_bbox(ex_cbg$geometry[1]) %>% unlist()

  element1 <- box_list[[1]]
  element2 <- box_list[[2]]
  element3 <- box_list[[3]]
  element4 <- box_list[[4]]
```

In other non-tileset queries, I have obtained the raster from the following code, which includes the bounding box constraints:

```
query_result <- GET(paste0("https://gis.smcgov.org/image/rest/services/SanMateoCounty_DEM2017/ImageServer/exportImage?bbox=",element1,",",element2,",",element3,",",element4,"&size=2500,2500&format=tiff&f=json"))

result <- raster(content(query_result)$href)
```

Comment: Just to make sure we understand, you want to treat the tilelayer as if it were a raster layer and download an image that is within a specified bounds (and is basically a handful of pasted-together tiles, then cropped to the bounds?)

Comment: @SethLutske Yes, that is what I am aiming for. Thanks for wording it in a clearer way.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a trivial task.  I could tell you how to do it in javascript, but it sounds like you're looking for a solution either in r, or something that can be created using the js api.  I would try this question on the arcgis geonet forum, its a very active community that may have a good method for you